# Undo/redo adding objects

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a custom banner maker program in which the following can be done:

- Different banner shapes can be selected (Buttons clicked to place the corresponding movieclip onto the stage)
- Different banner colors can be selected by using a `ColorTransform` that is linked to buttons i.e. a red button turns the banner red
- Textfields can be added to the stage, dragged and dropped using `startDrag` and `stopDrag`, and the text color can be changed with a `ColorPicker` as well as being able to change the font size and font itself
- Pre-loaded images can be selected from a panel and added to the banner (Buttons that are clicked to add a corresponding movieclip to the stage)
- Images can be uploaded directly onto the stage and can be resized

I need to figure out a way of being able to essentially add undo and redo features to do things like remove an image/textbox that was placed, change the banner color back to whatever color it was previously, reset the position of an object that was dragged from its default position etc.

I'm not sure how to best go about this using AS3?

Comment: Hi, would you care to take a look at my program if at all possible? It's around 500 lines of code and you're probably a much more established developer than I.

Comment: I'll take a look, but pastebin/github/Dropbox it

Comment: Alright is there a way I can send it to you privately?

Answer (score 0):

Not hard. Use removeChild(instance name of Child here) to remove an object from the stage.

Atriace's idea is sensible. You didn't say if you'll want to remember the positions of things **after** you stop running your program. Or is it only **while** you're running?

If the latter I'd create an array for each banner or textfield, and store in that array the current values of the properties you want to record. So, for instance:

```
var A:Array = new Array
A.push(textfield1.text)
```

will put your current text in textfield1 into the first index position in array A. You can call that little bit of code when you initially add the text (on a button click or whatever). Later, if you want that text back you'd do it like

```
textfield1.text = A[0]
```

assuming that your old text was in the first index position in the array.

If you want to remember values between runs of the program use a **SharedObject** to write the value to disk. Too much to write about that here -- look it up!

Comment: I only want the user to be able to undo/redo whilst the program is running yes. I am a little confused at the minute though; perhaps you could take a look at my code in its current state? The code has about 500 lines at the minute.